# Getting staircase output from openpyxl when importing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to import data from multiple sheets to another in excel, and in order to do this I need python to input the data into the first empty cell, instead of overwriting the data from the last file. It seems to almost work, however, each column is jumping to its "own" empty row, and not staying in the correct row with the rest of its matching data, creating a staircase type pattern.

This is my code

```
import os
import openpyxl
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\XX\\Desktop')

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test file python.xlsx', data_only = True) #open source excel file
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('test3.xlsx', data_only = True) #destination excel file
ws2 = wb2.active

#row_offset = ws2.max_row + 1

for i in range(10,150):
    for j in range(3,13):
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
        rowOffset = ws2.max_row + 1
        rowNum = rowOffset 
        ws2.cell(row = rowNum, column = j-2).value = c.value

wb2.save('test3.xlsx')
```

Here is a screenshot of the output in excel [Staircase output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P8At.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `ws2.max_row` each time you put something in `ws2` (i.e. - `ws2.cell(row = rowNum, column = j-2).value = c.value`) your `max_row` goes up by one affecting the entire loop creating that effect.

use `current_row = ws2.max_row` outside of the nested loop and it should fix your "staircase" issue.

Also, mind that when you run in the first iteration `max_row == 1` that is why your sheet starts at row 2 and not at row 1.